# Where can I get correct pitch parameter for SDL_RenderReadPixels function in SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have a texture created with SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET access and I want to get all it's pixels with SDL_RenderReadPixels() function. One of the function parameters is pitch and I don't really know where can I can get it.

Texture is created with dimensions of a previously created surface, but function call with surface->pitch as pitch parameter generates EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Texture and surface dimensions are 800x600, and surface->pitch returns 3200, which is strange for me, because I thought that pitch is the width of the texture in memory and expected surface->pitch to be something like 1024.

Comment: Pitch is the width of the texture **times** the size of a single pixel in bytes. E.g. for a 800x600 texture with 32-bit pixels (4 bytes), the pitch would be 3200 (800 × 4).

Comment: @zenith Thanks for the info, however it crashes with 3200 as pitch parameter. Any chance texture pitch changes somehow and I can get the correct one from it?

Answer (score 0):

The exact value of `pitch` depends on the pixel format and is always aligned to a 4-byte boundary.

```
static int
SDL_CalculatePitch(Uint32 format, int width)
{
    int pitch;

    if (SDL_ISPIXELFORMAT_FOURCC(format) || SDL_BITSPERPIXEL(format) >= 8) {
        pitch = (width * SDL_BYTESPERPIXEL(format));
    } else {
        pitch = ((width * SDL_BITSPERPIXEL(format)) + 7) / 8;
    }
    pitch = (pitch + 3) & ~3;   /* 4-byte aligning for speed */
    return pitch;
}
```

Taken from [SDL-mirror](https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/master/src/video/SDL_surface.c).